# {Q ∈P(A)||Q| = 2}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

{Q ∈P(A)||Q| = 2}
The following questions is about set partitions. For the set given, indicate whether it is a partition of the set A (for any A) and explain your answer.

I taught its not a partition 
since Q⊆A and |Q|=2 and if A={}(empty set).
then |A|=0 and since Q⊆A, Q cant have a cardinality greater then A.

is that what I am suppose to do...

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say we have set $A =$ {1,2,3}$so$$P(A)$ = {{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3},$\varnothing$ }

Q = {Q $ \in P(A) | |Q|= 2$} $\longrightarrow$ Q = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}

this can never be a partition of A since every Element appears twice (or more), which is always the case when you have 
a set with more than 2 Elements, which is necessary to have a $|Q| = 2$, except for the case that we have exactly $|A|=2$ but when its asked for A to be any set, it doesnt work!

Comment: thanks for clarifying the question for me. However i wanted to know what i did is it completely wrong i mean doesn't it help to conclude the answer by focusing on the cardinality ? and when u say Never does it mean even if we put the |Q| equal or lower then 1 or even |Q|=|A|. thanks again for your help

Comment: The importance is, to understand the definition or a partition! A partition is a set, which holds a certain combination of the elements of a given set in which every combination is disjunct to each other, means every element of the given set, can only appear once per combination of a partition. Every set has a certain spectrum of possible partition (Bell number) which says, how many possible combination of element combinations are available to a given set. The cardinality of the set Q and the set A doesnt really help to show that Q might or not might be a partition.

Comment: Interesting is, that it can only be a partition when  $|A|$ and $Q =$ {$Q \in P(A) | |Q| = |A|$ }, which refers to the element of $P(A)$ which has every element of $A$ in the single combination!

Comment: I just understood the question. Thanks a alot again.

Comment: Yes, you are right thats true I guess! :)